# Cannot remove an event listener outside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I add an event listener inside `useEffect`. It runs once after first rerender due to the **useEffect second argument(`[]`)**. Then I try to remove it outside `useEffect` (in handleSearch function) but it doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do with function scopes but don't understand it fully. Maybe there is a workaround?

```
const handleSearch = () => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', setPageHeightWrapper);
};

const [pageHeight, setPageHeight] = useState(0);

function setPageHeightWrapper() { setPageHeight(window.innerHeight); };
useEffect(() =>{
  window.addEventListener('resize', setPageHeightWrapper);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', setPageHeightWrapper);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `setPageHeightWrapper` is defined an inline function and when the component re-renders a new instance of it is created and while clearing an event listener you need to pass the same method which was passed while setting the listener.

On the other hand, when a useEffect hook is called it, gets the function reference from its closure and it uses the same reference to clear the listener.

A way to make the removeListener work outside of useEffect is to use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook

```
const handleSearch = () => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', memoHeightWrapper);
};

const [pageHeight, setPageHeight] = useState(0);


const memoHeightWrapper = useCallback(() => {
    setPageHeight(window.innerHeight);
})
useEffect(() =>{
  window.addEventListener('resize', memoHeightWrapper);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', memoHeightWrapper);
  };
}, []);
```