# How to add a ClassName and remove it onScroll event in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm trying to make a Sticky Header that can change its background-color based on his position on the page. To do that, I'm trying to add a className "active" to my Styled Component "StyledHeader" that will appears when the scrollPositionY is above 400px and disappear when below.

In other words, what I want to do is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/1e8k9q8b/) but using React.JS, JSX syntax and Styled Components.

Here's what I have for now:

```
import { Link } from '@reach/router';

import DuskLogo from '../images/dusk_logo.svg';

import { 
    StyledHeader, 
    StyledDuskLogo
} from '../styles/StyledHeader';

const Header = () => (
<StyledHeader>
  <div className="header-content">
    <Link to="/">
    <StyledDuskLogo src={DuskLogo} alt="dusk-logo" />
    </Link>
  </div>
</StyledHeader>
)

export default Header;
```

Do you know a simple way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an event listener in your `useEffect`. when you scroll down the value of `window.scrollY` will increase such as 1, 2, ...100 .. (in px) and update your `color` in `useState` as per the  [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY).  try something like this

```
const StyledBody = window.styled.div`
  background: lightgray;
  height: 5000px;
`;

const StyledText = window.styled.h4`
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 40px;
`;

const StyledHeader = window.styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
`;

const Header = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("rgba(17, 42, 107, 0.7)");

  const handleScroll = React.useCallback((event) => {
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;

      //console.log(scrollTop );  //1,2,...100,...200...etc (in px)

      if (scrollTop >= 20 && scrollTop < 50) {
        setColor("yellow");
      }

      if (scrollTop >= 50 && scrollTop < 90) {
        setColor("red");
      }

      if (scrollTop >= 90 && scrollTop < 120) {
        setColor("green");
      }
      if (scrollTop >= 120 && scrollTop < 150) {
        setColor("blue");
      }
      if (scrollTop >= 150 && scrollTop < 180) {
        setColor("violet");
      }
      if (scrollTop >= 180 && scrollTop < 210) {
        setColor("purple");
      }
});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, false);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledBody>
      <StyledHeader color={color}>
        <StyledText>My background color changes</StyledText>
      </StyledHeader>
    </StyledBody>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

here is a working demo ..change the code as per your need.[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blueseal/hLjq1bex/50/)

Edit: I have added styled-components for you. check it out and let me know whether it works for you. to know more about these hooks go to [`useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465182/5124488) and [`useCallback`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569923/5124488)

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answer, but I can't get it to work on my project. I do not see how I could target Header or "StyledHeader" instead of "#app". Mainly because Header become a div with only a random generated class. I've also tried to apply a class to the Header and target it, but it doesn't seems to work too. I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: @Dabu I have updated my code. let me know whether it works

Answer (score 0):

haven't run this code myself but could be something like:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const headerEl = React.useRef();
  const [offsetTop, setOffsetTop] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll, false); // to remove scroll event on unmount
    };
  }, []);

  const onScroll = () => setOffsetTop(headerEl.current.offsetTop);

  return (
    <StyledHeader ref={headerEl} className={offsetTop > 400 ? "active" : ""}>
      ...
    </StyledHeader>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work unfortunately, offsetTop keeps returning 0 for me